# Extract 'end' locations from multiple locations in str_locate_all in R?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

If we locate a substring among a vector of strings like so

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

x <- c("ldksfABCskdlfj",
       "kABCz",
       "skdlfjlsjfABCksdfpjfkj")

x %>% str_locate_all("ABC")
```

we get

```
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     6   8

[[2]]
     start end
[1,]     2   4

[[3]]
     start end
[1,]    11  13
```

How can I extract *just the **end** locations*? (i.e. 8, 4, 13)

#### What I've tried so far

```
x %>% str_locate_all("ABC") %>% sapply(function(x) { .[1,2] })
# Error in .[1, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there. Here's a way to do:

```
x %>% str_locate_all("ABC") %>% sapply(., function(x) x[,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one match in each string as shown in the example you can use `str_locate` instead which will avoid use of any loops to extract the `"end"` column as you can directly subset from the matrix returned.

```
stringr::str_locate(x, "ABC")[, 2]
#[1]  8  4 13
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
str_locate(x, "ABC") %>% 
        as_tibble %>% 
        pull(end)
 #[1]  8  4 13
```